# Test to compare frequencies?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, frequency

[image: Pollinator Data]

I want to be able to see if an insect has a statistical preference for flower colour, which test should I use as the data is frequencies and I assume using Chi-squared wouldn't work. For example I would want to know if Diptera was more likely to visit white flowers than any other colour.

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly do you assume Chi 2 wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the data are counts, you may very well use a chi-squared test: if you have a hypothesis (formulated prior to visualising the data!) on what the data should look like, you can test it using goodness of fit chi-squared. Otherwise you can just use a homogeneity chi-squared test.

Note that this works because the data in your table aren't actually frequencies, they're actual counts. If you had frenquecies with no idea of the sample size it would be a different story (nothing could be said as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

Given that your observed variable is a count variable, you may use a Poisson regression model to test the hypothesis that the counts for the different colours could result from the same lambda parameter in the population. You can model the different colour categories using dummy variables.

ln(lambda) = b0 + b_blue&green + b_pink + ...

count ~ Poisson(lambda)